# How can I use Ubuntu 12.04 server to play a repeating video loop on a connected tv?

Tags: 12.04, server, video, tv

I would like to use ubuntu server 12.04 to play a repeating video loop on a connected tv.  There won't be any interaction with the system once it is live, except remotely.

Additionally, I need to be able to push an updated video file/files to the server remotely and have them play as soon as they are done.  I'm not worried about the technology required to send the files to the server as I can handle that, but I would like to know which video player for ubuntu server to use and how to set up the server to play video.

So the ideal setup would be we just connect this server to a tv, turn it on, and then it begins playing the video loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install ubuntu-desktop (or any other way that you are comforatble with, that gives you a working X server).

As for pushing files there is a million different ways, you could use rsync, or CIFS or AFP.

Create a service that runs constantly in the background. (I would use Python and [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/)).

This service can:

- Start VLC with the `--fullscreen` and `--loop` arguments.
- Use [inotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify) to detect newly uploaded files, and restart VLC (or maybe just update a playlist?).

Comment: Your solution is working great, however I have one question:  When I push files to the computer, how can I have vlc load that new file after the video loop is done (or immediately).  I'm assuming deleting the existing file while vlc is playing it is not a good idea?

Comment: Once you have the upstart script build you will need to open a shell and enter `restart the-script-name` to change anything.  You **can** delete the file while it still running but it won't affect vlc. This is until you restart the script.

Comment: @thnee If it isn't too much trouble: could you provide a working upstart script?

Comment: Edited my answer to accomodate for reloading VLC when new files are uploaded.

Comment: @MadMike No I will not be able to author a complete solution, sorry.